# How to empty the search box after submit in ajax jquery submit without page refresh?

Tags: ajax

I need a ajax submission system without page refresh, I found one from the [submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery script site](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/)

After remove `jquery-ajax\images\form_bg.png`, How to empty the search box after submit the data? Can anyone add a small code for me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Try this:



          $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "your-php-file.php",
               success: function(get_ajax_return_value){
                 $('#yoursearchbox_id').val('');
               }
             });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#searchbox_id').val('');
```